# Работа со списком и текстовым файлом

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, list

Помогите, пожалуйста, с заданием. Нужно в списке `prev_data_dict` обработать каждый его элемент с помощью функции `blockcypher.get_total_balance('тут название переменной')` и записать в файл с названием `prev_balance.txt` построчно (каждый элемент в каждой строке).

```
with open(r'prev_data.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as prev_fl:
    # получим список всех строк
    prev_data_lines = prev_fl.readlines()
    # на основе списка создадим словарь ключ:значение
    prev_data_dict = {ln.split(';')[0]:ln.split(';')[1] for ln in prev_data_lines}
    # превращение словаря в список ключей prev_data_dict
    prev_data_lines_adr = prev_data_dict.keys()
```

Comment: Так а в чём проблема? Где остальной код?

Comment: @dIm0n К сожалению у меня мало опыта в python, из за этого я не могу понять как это сделать

Comment: Приведённый код вы сами написали или это часть задания?

Comment: @dIm0n Сам написал. Могу обьяснить что я делал до этого, если надо

Comment: Ну если вы сами его написали, то я не понимаю, почему вы не можете дописать остальное тогда :) Файл открывать вы умеете, в цикле вызывать функции тоже, остаётся только запись в файл - `print` или `write`, думаю про них вы тоже должны знать, если читать из файла умеете

Comment: @dIm0n Я вроде все основы знаю, но не понимаю как мне все это объединить. Можно сказать что я просто запутался. Буду очень благодарен если вы мне напишите решение. Так сказать, распутаете меня :)

Comment: @dIm0n Извините за беспокойство, мне ждать от вас помощи или нет? Если нет напишите хоть примерно. Мне просто очень нужно

Comment: это дубль вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1156561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba/1157079#1157079

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, лучше сделать так:

```
with open(r'prev_data.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as prev_fl:
    prev_data_lines = prev_fl.readlines()

prev_data_dict = {ln.split(';')[0]:ln.split(';')[1] for ln in prev_data_lines}
prev_data_lines_adr = prev_data_dict.keys()
```

Comment: А где тут обработка и запись в файл?

Comment: А где у него обработка и запись в файл?

Comment: *обработать каждый его элемент с помощью функции `blockcypher.get_total_balance('тут название переменной')` и записать в файл с названием `prev_balance.txt` построчно*

Comment: Я тоже могу так написать: "Сначала сделайте как показал я, а потом обработайте каждый его элемент с помощью функции `blockcypher.get_total_balance('тут название переменной')` и запишите в файл с названием `prev_balance.txt` построчно."  
Почему-то когда кто-то задаёт вопрос по типу: "Мне на конкурсе сказали сделать вот такую задачу, но я ничего не знаю, решать даже не пробовал, кода и каких-то своих наработок нет. Сделайте за меня, пожалуйста!!!", то такие вопросы часто закрывают и это правильно, так и надо. Так почему же здесь я должен писать за него то, что он сам не потрудился?

Comment: Разве из вашего комментария не следует, что вы не должны были давать **ответ** в таком случае, а дать **комментарий** или минус, например? :)

Comment: Здесь человек написал хоть что-то. И на основании этого что-то я и дал ответ

Comment: Ну так вопрос был в том, чтобы дописать код, а вы изменили текущий код автора, а не дописали новый. Поэтому есть два пути: вы считаете, что дописывать нехорошо без собственных попыток и говорите об этом автору/ставите минус и т.п., но не пишите это в ответе, либо вы действительно отвечаете на вопрос, дописав этот недостающий код. Иначе получается, что ваш ответ не отвечает на вопрос