# Как построчно применить функцию к списку/переменной с переносами строк

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
import blockcypher
prev_data_lines_adr = ['14CaBzRbZDuGJCAdu9CZsbrCfyv4K7f7sf','0xd4FD252d7D2C9479a8d616F510eAC6243B5DDdf9']
for ln in prev_data_lines_adr:
    blockcypher.get_total_balance(ln)
```

Как изменить код, чтобы функция построчно применилась к списку или переменной с переносами строк. После выполнения функции, нужно записать выполненное назад в список либо в переменной с переносами строк

Comment: Возможно [О функции map](https://pyneng.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/book/10_useful_functions/map.html)?

Comment: @ShamusRezol Видимо я что-то не понимаю.
`map(blockcypher.get_total_balance(prev_data_lines_adr), prev_data_lines_adr)`
Выдает ошибку

Comment: Что же? `map(Function, List)`. Каждый член List (item) становится `Function(item)`. Возвращается итерируемый объект.

Comment: Может `map(blockcypher.get_total_balance, prev_data_lines_addr)`? Я не очень то понимаю, что именно вы хотите сделать, поэтому и не пишу ответом.

Comment: @ShamusRezol Все так, кроме того что в этой функции в скобках должна быть строка либо переменная. Как быть тогда?

Comment: Вы не пытаетесь понять. Каждый элемент prev_data_lines_addr будет передан в функцию(или же класс) blockcypher.get_total_balance. map вернет итерируемый объект результатов.

Comment: @ShamusRezol Спасибо, разобрался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого есть map, который первым параметром принимает метод, который должен возвращать что-то, а вторым итерируемый объект. Map применит метод к каждому элементу итерируемого объекта и вернет генератор.

```
a = tuple(map(lambla x: x + 1, [1,2,3]))
print(a)
# (2,3,4)
```

А еще можно воспользоваться любым из comprehension

```
# генератор
a = (x + 1 for x in [1,2,3])
print(a)
# генератор
print(*a) # сработает только один раз. генератор же.
# 2 3 4

# list
a = [x + 1 for x in [1,2,3]]
print(a)
# [2,3,4]

# tuple
a = tuple(x + 1 for x in [1,2,3])
print(a)
# (2,3,4)
```

С генератором, что удобно это то, что генератор будет выполняться по элементно при необходиомсти. Что может быть важно при работе например с большим файлом.

```
# например нам нужно прочитать файл построчно и убрать из каждой строки 
# переносы символов и пустые строки
with open("file.txt", "r") as source:
    lines = (x.strip() for x in source if x.strip())
# теперь у нас есть генератор lines, который еще ничего не сделал, 
# а делать он будет когда мы захотим проитерировать по нему 
# и делать будет по строчно.
```

Чаще всего включения получаются горадо понятнее чем применение map и filter

```
# Перепишем построчно один файл в другой без загрузки всего файла в ОЗУ.
# А также применим фильтр по длине строки

with open("source.txt", "r") as source, open("dest.txt", "w") as dest:
    _ = tuple(dest.write(x) for x in source if len(x) < 10)
```

```
# Перепишем построчно один файл в другой без загрузки всего файла в ОЗУ.
# А также применим фильтр по длине строки

with open("source.txt", "r") as source, open("dest.txt", "w") as dest:
    _ = tuple(map(dest.write, filter(lambda x: len(x) < 10, source)))
```

map и filter ленивые функции возвращающие генератор, который еще ничего не сделал. генератор итерируется только один раз и его нужно проитерировать для получения результатов.